# MacBook Pro 16" battery drains overnight

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, catalina, battery, sleep-wake

I've had this Mac on Catalina 10.15.5 for a few weeks now and suddenly noticed this battery drain overnight. It went from 60% to 3% two nights ago and happening last night too. After doing some digging I noticed that com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.remindd.time-alarm seems to be waking up the Mac every few secs. Googling it says that it's related to scheduled reminders which I have a few of but disabling those hasn't helped either. I've attached a snippet of the pmset log below. Basically these set of lines repeat all night, even when the lid is shut. Can someone please help?

```
2020-06-26 13:30:24 +0530 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:100%) 76 secs   
2020-06-26 13:30:29 +0530 Wake Requests         [*process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=2562 wakeAt=2020-06-26 14:13:11] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=40962 wakeAt=2020-06-27 00:53:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=19771 wakeAt=2020-06-26 19:00:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.remindd.time-alarm,326"]           
2020-06-26 13:30:29 +0530 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(1965 ms)] [mDNSResponder is slow(5016 ms)]           
2020-06-26 13:31:38 +0530 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [powerd is slow(5020 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(311 ms)] [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(357 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(353 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1015 ms)]           
2020-06-26 13:31:40 +0530 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [RP17 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(738 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(955 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(953 ms)] [PEG0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(498 ms)]
```

I also noticed that certain scheduled tasks are listed multiple times in the System Information > Power > Next Scheduled Events?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start Terminal.app and check if there are any scheduled events

```
pmset -g sched
```

and try to clear them with

```
sudo pmset sched cancelall
```

You might also want to check the file that stores the times the Mac should wake up for some maintenance. The appropriate commands would be:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist
```

and

```
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist
```

In case any of those are corrupted, maybe deleting them might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop powernap first, sounds like a culprit to me. I mean try to cycle it off/on and rebooting if you really use it otherwise make sure it's off

Comment: I don't use PowerNap and have it off for both battery and Power Adapter. Every log entry seems to reference this process com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.remindd.time-alarm which is apparently related to the reminders app.

Comment: I got it, try sudoing pmset to defaults and then disable powernap again

Comment: What would the command be to restore to defaults? Wouldn't the restore defaults in Energy Saver do the same thing?

Comment: Try `sudo pmset` and take a look at `man pmset`

Comment: Issue persists even with PowerNap disabled

Comment: Hmm, there is a Power consumption tab in activity monitor. Take a look a it maybe, another thing to consider is to install xcode and run a performance trace in instruments. If I recall correctly you can track power consumption there with a specific instrument config  either per process or globally. I'm gonna check this myself in couple of hours and I'll let you know.

Comment: You may also take a look at `defaults read` for a domains list to read from do `defaults domains` also `sudo defaults read` will grab global settings instead of user space.